# jQuery UI Autocomplete - get data from txt file

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

I'm jQuery beginner trying to make jQuery UI Autocomplete get data from txt file. Txt format is simple:

> user1
>   user2
>   user3
>   etc.

Code is:

```
jQuery.get('users.txt', function(usersGet) {
    $( "#userLogin" ).autocomplete( {
        source: usersGet
    });
});
```

But unfortunately that does not work. Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: check it in some debugger e.g. firebug what errors you are encountering?

Comment: and check if usersGet is filled or not?

Comment: Hi Guys,
firebug says:
CONSOLE -> GET users.txt (Response):
user1
user2
user3.

Displayed in column. So, I'm fetching user list, but somehow autocomplete tooltip does not appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **Source**
>   An Array of Strings:
>   [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
>
> An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
>   [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

You need to amend your text file to be in this format:

```
["user1","user2","user3"]
```

Then change your jQuery to this:

```
$( "#userLogin" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'users.txt'
});
```

Comment: It's OK now. I just poorly joined jQ js file!

Comment: Hi once again,

autocomplete bubble is showing up, but when I type something in input, tooltip is showing ALL entrys from list, even that not mathing... for ex. I can type: "aaaazzzz" and still have autocomplete bubble (in list there is NO such string)... There is more than 1600 users/elements in users.txt - but problem occurs even when I reduced list to 5 entrys. My script is like Rory wrote.

Comment: @rw79 you're probably best starting a new question for that problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685975/jquery-ui-autocomplete-tooltip-is-showing-all-entrys-from-list-even-that-not

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution did not work for me. This is how I read a `.txt` for my jQuery autocomplete input field:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "foo/bar.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        var autoCompleteData = data.split('\n');
        $("#input").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(autoCompleteData, request.term);
                response(results.slice(0, 10)); // Display the first 10 results
            }
        });
    }
});
```