# Autocomplete and Array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, autocomplete

I'm new to Javascript and I'm trying to create an array to use for Autocomplete plugin.
The plugin is working perfectly with the following code:

```
countries = new Array();
countries[0]='United States';

'use strict';


$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: countries,
    minChars: 2,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        //I will put something here soon.
    }
});
```

But when I try to create an array from a text file, I can't create the array even though the code seems fine.

```
$.get('test.txt', function(data){
   var array = data.split(',');
   var i = 0;
   array.forEach(function(insert) {
   countries[i]=insert;
   i++;
   });
});
```

Any reason why it would not insert the data in the text file to the countries array? It seems to me that everything I do should work.
By the way, no worries, the test.txt file is just fine (United States,Mexico).

Thanks ahead and have a great day.

Comment: Possible duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682901/jquery-ui-autocomplete-get-data-from-txt-file

Comment: Can you not have the text file as a javascript array? I normally use Ajax to bring in a .js file which is formed as a Javascript Array already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.get` is an *asynchronous function*, so by the time `autocomplete` method is executed, `countries` would have got no element from the file. So, move the `autocomplete` function to the callback of `$.get` like this

```
$.get('test.txt', function(data) {
    var array = data.split(',');
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        lookup: array,
        minChars: 2,
        onSelect: function(suggestion) {
            //I will put something here soon.
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you don't have to populate `countries` like you did in the question. You can simply pass the array returned by JavaScript's `split` function, as it is.

Comment: Shouldn't this work assuming that `$.get` is put above the autocomplete function? I've done something similar using `$.ajax` instead of get and it works ok.

Comment: @Scironic Even if it is above the `autocomplete`, since the execution is asynchronous, `countries` will be filled only after executing `autocomplete`

Comment: @thefourtheye. So in an example where I have a js file with an array (tags = [1,2,3,4,etc]) which is pulled in through an Ajax request and then the autocomplete function is run after - what's happening differently?

Comment: @Scironic Can you create a sample fiddle, so that I can look at the flow of control?

Comment: @thefourtheye. [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/aNuf2/). I haven't attached any HTML or real files due to time constraints - I also removed a lot of irrelevant bloat - but that's the main part of what I was doing.

Comment: @Scironic Ah, your case is different. You are executing `autocomplete` in `done`. jQuery makes sure to execute `done` only after getting response from the AJAX call. That is why your code works :-)

Comment: That makes sense! The codes partially ripped off of someone elses work so I'm not entirely familiar with it!

Comment: @thefourtheye. as an afterthought, which would be better? to execute after `.done`, or within `.get`?

Comment: @Scironic If you look at the code, we are nesting when we execute `autocomplete` within `get`. But, when we do it in `done`, it becomes linear. So, people prefer the `done` way.