# Jquery autocomplete from .txt file into node express app

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Relevant parts of project folder (node express skeleton) is as follows with a folder of views that has ejs file, using jquery, and trying to import the `univ_list.txt` file:

[image]

The .txt file is all ready and all i need to do is run a `.split(',')` on it so i can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682901/jquery-ui-autocomplete-get-data-from-txt-file) to it so I can have an autocomplete `input` file for my textbox but every time I run this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "http://localhost:3000/univ_list.txt" ).done(function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
```

It says not found. I've looked all over and people this seems to be the simplest solution for people but I've been moving this around for the past 2 hours and can't get anything. I'm shot. Can someone help please

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your relationship to the text file is not correct. I would try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get("univ_list.txt", function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

If that works successfully, you can then do the same in Autocomplete:

```
$(selector).autocomplete({
    source: 'univ_list.txt'
});
```

If this does not work, please describe the folder structure and relationship better.

Comment: When I do that or anything else I get a `404 not found` and then a link to where it looked, for example `http://localhost:3000/users/professionals/univ_list.txt` but I don't know how else to add the `.txt` file to the express app cause everytime I try in `app.js` i get an error

Comment: so I can sucessfully get all the text into the application by loading it into `users.js` which is an approved route, but I can't pass it into the `ejs` file because for some reason taking in strings in object form from `.render` causes an error in my browser saying it can't read the information when it clearly can. Can this even be done using just jQuery with an array/.txt of this size?